# How to parse the result of requests.get to produce the needed data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get some data from a url using the code below. I need help to produce the needed output.

```
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  import requests
  page = requests.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/new/")
  pagedata = page.text
  print ("* ", pagedata)
```

My output: (Truncated)

```
  <a href="/currencies/cheems-token/" class="cmc-link"><div data-sensors-click="true" class="sc-aef7b723-0 sc-8497df48-0 iULUNk">
  <img class="coin-logo" src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/24988.png" alt="Cheems logo"/><
  div class="sc-aef7b723-0 sc-8497df48-1 iATetF name-area ">
  <p font-weight="semibold" color="text" font-size="1" data-sensors-click="true" class="sc-4984dd93-0 kKpPOn">Cheems</p>
  <div data-nosnippet="true" class="sc-8497df48-2 gtUrBF"><div class="sc-8497df48-3 erCSsg">1</div>
  <p color="text3" class="sc-4984dd93-0 iqdbQL coin-item-symbol" font-size="1" data-sensors-click="true">Cheems</p></div></div></div></a></td>
  <td style="text-align:end"><span>$0.00000005918</span></td><td style="text-align:end"><span class="sc-97d6d2ca-0 bQjSqS">
  <span class="icon-Caret-down"></span>19.90%</span></td><td style="text-align:end"><span class="sc-97d6d2ca-0 cYiHal">
  <span class="icon-Caret-up"></span>58.53%</span></td><td style="text-align:end"><div class="sc-abe52752-3 eSDaBL">--</div></td>
  <td style="text-align:end">$3,774,982</td><td style="text-align:end">
  <div class="sc-abe52752-3 eSDaBL"><img src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/24091.png"/>zkSync</div></td>
  <td style="text-align:end">3 hours ago</td><td><div class="sc-aef7b723-0 dDQUel">
```

Output Wanted:

```
  Name      Symbol    Price             1h        24h         MarketCap     Volume        Blockchain
  Cheems    Cheems    $0.00000005918    19.90%    58.53%      ---           $3,774,982    zkSync
  CLIPS     Clips     $0.00005811       10.38%    9.44%       $12,697,441   $45,436,152   Ethereum  
  Pooh Inu  POOH      $0.0...07305      17.69%    87.04%      $1,497,586    $332,306      BNB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can use [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) with a bit of *post-processing* :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

usecols = ["Name", "Symbol", "Price", "1h", "24h", "MarketCap", "Volume", "Blockchain"]

df = pd.read_html("https://coinmarketcap.com/new/")[0]

df[["Name", "Symbol"]] = df["Name"].str.split(r"\d+", expand=True)

df = df.rename(columns={"Fully Diluted Market Cap": "MarketCap"})[usecols]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

            Name      Symbol           Price      1h      24h     MarketCap       Volume Blockchain
0         Cheems      Cheems  $0.00000006134   3.64%   64.31%            --   $4,361,803     zkSync
1          Clips       CLIPS     $0.00005213  10.28%   18.75%   $11,391,728  $43,346,358   Ethereum
2       Pooh Inu        POOH    $0.0...08057  10.29%  106.29%    $1,651,664     $338,030        BNB
..           ...         ...             ...     ...      ...           ...          ...        ...
27  Mexican Pepe     MEXPEPE   $0.0000000617  19.14%   78.02%       $61,704      $94,416   Ethereum
28    AIBabyDoge  AIBABYDOGE    $0.0...01419   7.50%   74.99%      $595,903      $22,701   Ethereum
29      MonoLend         MLD          $0.143   1.38%    3.51%  $285,937,514      $18,166    Polygon

[30 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: I am getting an error "invalid character in identifier"

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Can you show your code and where the error occurs ?

Comment: I just copy and pasted your code your code. A dialog box appears Syntax error then the message in the box is invalid character in identifier. Im searching what might have caused this.

Comment: I think it's a formatting issue when copy/pasting from *Jupyterlab*. I fixed it. Can you try again, please ?

Comment: No more syntax error but Im getting this raise ValueError("No tables found"). By the way Im using python 3.8.10

Comment: Its working now, I dont know what went wrong. Thank you for your help.

Comment: One thing I noticed, sometimes it displays the output and sometimes raise ValueError("No tables found"). Has it something to do with connecting to the url?

Comment: I have no idea why and I can’t reproduce the issue when running the code multiple times in a raw. Maybe it has to do with the source website ?

Comment: Can you replace the link in my code with `page.text` (*that you defined in your code*) ?

Comment: That is what I did and it very fine. Is it possible to display the output in one screen? There is this [30 rows x 6 columns] at the end of the line.

Comment: Great, you can use `print(df.to_string())`.

Comment: The script worked perfectly in my environment (Monterey 12.6.5, Python 3.10.9, Pandas 1.5.3, without requests 2.28.2). Could it be encoding or something? (My env: LANG="", LC_COLLATE="C", LC_CTYPE="UTF-8", LC_MESSAGES="C", LC_MONETARY="C", LC_NUMERIC="C", LC_TIME="C", LC_ALL=).

Answer (score 1):

**How about using Pandas `read_html`?**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

page = requests.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/new/")
pagedata = page.text

tables = pd.read_html(pagedata)  # A list of DataFrame(s)
# Result. Try [1], [2], etc. if the page contains multiple tables.
table = tables[0]  # A DataFrame
```

**Tweaks:** Then, we need some tweaks.

```
# 1. Check the original header
>>> table.columns
Index(['Unnamed: 0', '#', 'Name', 'Price', '1h', '24h',
   'Fully Diluted Market Cap', 'Volume', 'Blockchain', 'Added',
   'Unnamed: 10'], dtype='object')

# 2. Select columns to use
columns = [
    'Name', 'Price', '1h', '24h', 'Fully Diluted Market Cap', 'Volume',
    'Blockchain']
table = table[columns]  # Unwanted columns are removed

# 3. Split 'Name' column data (str) with digit(s) (r'\d+') as a delimiter, and
# Name the resultant DataFrame 'sub_table'
sub_table = table['Name'].str.split(r'\d+', regex=True, expand=True)  # DataFrame
sub_table.columns = ['Name', 'Symbol']  # Rename columns

# 4. JOIN the tables (Not really JOIN, but some kind of...)
table_new = table.copy(deep=True)  # This is for safety's sake
table_new[['Name', 'Symbol']] = sub_table  # Almost done

# 5. Relocate and rename the columns as you like
my_order = [
    'Name', 'Symbol', 'Price', '1h', '24h', 'Fully Diluted Market Cap',
    'Volume', 'Blockchain']
table_new = table_new[my_order]
table_new.rename(
    columns={'Fully Diluted Market Cap': 'Market Cap'}, inplace=True)  # DONE!
```

For the details please refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html